# nivo responsivebar chart - bar width collapsing when screen is refreshed

Tags: reactjs, sass, nivo-react

Recently started using the Nivo charting library. Having issues with **ResponsiveBar** in that it draws nicely after a recompile but if I F5 reload the bars collapse to near zero width. The surrounding chart isn't resized - only the width of the contained svg objects for each bar item.

To compensate Im having to use `barComponent=` and set a minimum width. This is less than ideal as I lose the nice tooltips, etc.

If I trigger a resize event the bars reappear at the appropriate width.

Im new to this library so Im not clear where to look for what Im doing wrong.

Note that this doesn't happen with **ResponsiveLine**.

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: There are some custom draw hooks you can use to circumvent this... But I ended up ditching nivo as it was fighting back too hard.