# Issue rendering Nivo's ResponsiveBar

Tags: css, reactjs, data-visualization, bar-chart, nivo-react

I am trying to make a very simple bar chart using Nivo's Responsive Bar (official docs [here](https://nivo.rocks/bar/)) in my React application (React v18).

I have managed to set up a basic bar chart but it is acting funny.

When I load the page, it is **empty**. See screenshot
[image]

If I navigate to another page of my app and then navigate back to the page where the bar chart is, it suddenly shows the bars but they're very **thin and definitely not aligned well** (they are not vertically aligned with the labels on the x-axis). Pic:
[image]

Finally, if I am on the page where there is the bar chart (regardless of whether it is displayed as empty or with the thin bars) and I go into my code and make any change (literally even add a space somewhere) either to the bar chart component or to the one that imports it and renders it, **the bar chart re-loads and is displayed correctly**. see pic:
[image]

This is the bar chart code I wrote:

```
// install (please make sure versions match peerDependencies)
// yarn add @nivo/core @nivo/bar
import { ResponsiveBar } from '@nivo/bar'

const data = [
    {
      day: "Monday",
      degress: 59
    },
    {
      day: "Tuesday", 
      degress: 61
    },
    {
      day: "Wednesday",
      degress: 55
    },
    {
      day: "Thursday",
      degress: 78
    },
    {
      day: "Friday",
      degress: 71
    },
    {
      day: "Saturday",
      degress: 56
    },
    {
      day: "Sunday",
      degress: 67
    }
  ];

// make sure parent container have a defined height when using
// responsive component, otherwise height will be 0 and
// no chart will be rendered.
// website examples showcase many properties,
// you'll often use just a few of them.
const FPPTBarChart = () => {
    return (
      <ResponsiveBar 
        data={data}
        keys={["degress"]}
        indexBy="day"
        margin={{ top: 50, right: 130, bottom: 50, left: 60 }}
        padding={0.4}
        valueScale={{ type: "linear" }}
        colors="#3182CE"
        animate={true}
        enableLabel={false}
        axisTop={null}
        axisRight={null}
        axisLeft={{
          tickSize: 5,
          tickPadding: 5,
          tickRotation: 0,
          legend: "degrees",
          legendPosition: "middle",
          legendOffset: -40
        }}
      />
    );
};

export default FPPTBarChart;
```

What is causing this weird behaviour? Is there a way of fixing it? I am inclined to think that it is an issue with the library rather than with my code (this is because I have tweaked my code in many ways and tried snippets from the official docs as well as various codesandbox snippets).
I am aware that Nivo is not yet fully compatible with React 18 so I had to install Nivo components using `--legacy-peer-deps`, (as recommended [here](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/issues/1967)). Could that be the root of the issue? I already have both Nivo's ResponsiveLine and Nivo's ResponsivePie in my app and they both seem to be working just fine. Plus, I did a lot of research on this and could not find anything aside from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72653305/nivo-responsivebar-chart-bar-width-collapsing-when-screen-is-refreshed) stack overflow post, despite the fact that Nivo is a very widespread library. If this was an issue with the library itself/its compatibility with React 18 then surely I should that a lot of people are in my same boat?  I am confused..

This is a very annoying issue and I am wondering whether I'd be better off just dropping Nivo as a library and transitioning to an alternative such as react-chart-js-2, but I wanted to make sure it's not something that can be fixed before I make this rather big transition.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation than you, I upgraded to React 18 and installed dependencies with **"--legacy-peer-deps"**. It seems to be the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Hi nils! I have reverted my application back to React 17 and everything works fine. I suggest doing the same unless you really need any of the React 18 features :)

Answer (score -1):

Happened exactly the same with me, restarting the system did the trick.